# Screen has no signal after turning PC on

Tags: hdmi

I have a PC with a Gigabyte GTX 470 connected via HDMI to a Samsung screen. And like every 5th time or so when I turn it on the screen says "no signal" and is black.

I don't understand why this happens the solution to this is usually to reboot it and then it works again. I don't have the slightest idea what might could go wrong..

Comment: Does the same issue occur with DVI/VGA?

Comment: Just tried with the dvi-to-hdmi cable, didn't work either.. The graphics card does not have a VGA output..

Comment: Just reseted the bios and it works again.. but I still have no idea what was causing trouble..

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows 7, there is a fix to keep HDMI working when a PC is rebooted included in Win7 SP1

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be prudent to contact Gigabyte technical support or the vendor you bought it from to see if there is a known issue with the card and possibly get it replaced as the behavior could worsen over time.

Comment: From where do you want to know weather it's Gigabytes fault or not?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue with Gigabyte GTX 560 connected via HDMI to an AOC LED monitor. When connected via HDMI the screen goes blank intermittently. Have never been able to root-cause this issue although if it's a result of OS/driver glitches then it's tolerable. What I am more interested in is whether this can be in any way related to any input power-related issues. My system has a history of tiny electrical shocks which were never root-caused. Connecting via DVI-I/D works fine.